# Could not pick GraphicsDeviceType on Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini - Game fails to launch

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, unity-webgl, samsung-galaxy

I am currently working on an AR-based game using Unity and have encountered a perplexing issue when trying to run the game on a Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini. Everything was working fine on the Unity Editor and other simulator platforms, but when I switched to the Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini simulator platform, I started receiving the following warining:

> Could not pick GraphicsDeviceType, the game would fail to launch UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

I have tried searching for information on this error, but I couldn't find a specific solution or relevant discussions. It seems to be related to the graphics device type selection during the game launch process, but I'm not sure how to address it.

Here are some details about my setup:

- Unity version: 2021.3.10f1
- AR framework used: Vuforia
- Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini simulator platform selected

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue when targeting Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini or a similar device? Any insights, suggestions, or workarounds would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!